# Конкурентные операции

Tags: concurrency

Всем привет
Появилась пара заданий в учебном курсе, в которых требуется, например,сделать запись значений в мапу КОНКУРЕНТНО, возвести значения в квардрат КОНКУРЕНТНО и еще несколько в которых тоже что-то нужно деать КОНКУРЕНТНО. Я вот никак не могу понять, что значит конкурентно?  Моржет ли кто-нибудь привести пример именно конкурентных операций, но настолько простой пример, как будто ребенку показывать будете.

Если важно то язык go, но не думаю что такие вещи привязаны к языку

Вот как я понял.
Задача
ё

`Написать программу, которая конкурентно рассчитает значение квадратов чисел взятых из массива (2,4,6,8,10) и выведет их квадраты в stdout.`

Вот какое у меня решение если под конкурентностью подразумевается параллельные вычисления.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func square(num int) {
    fmt.Println(num * num)
    // fmt.Fprintln(os.Stdout, num*num)
}

func do() {
    nums := [...]int{2, 4, 6, 8, 10}
    for _, num := range nums {
        go square(num)//параллельные вызовы square
    }
    fmt.Scanln()
}
```

Comment: Зря вы отбросили специфику языка. Судя по вот этой ссылке https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/concurrency-in-go/9781491941294/ch04.html мне кажется без `defer` тут не будет параллельности. Хотя я `golang` не знаю, могу ошибаться. Но там в коде сплошной `defer` в паре с `go`.

Comment: @CrazyElf defer это отложеноое выполнение
то что идет после defer выполняется после выполнения всего того что идет после него

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, это плохая калька с английского **concurrent**, т.е. **одновременно** или **параллельно**.
Когда несколько операций выполняются параллельными потоками. Например, есть числа от 1 до 10 и вы их многопоточно возводите в квадрат, чтобы затратить на это меньше времени. Или что-то записываете в какой-то контейнер из разных потоков. И т.п.

**Update**: Как правильно замечают в комментарии, есть мнение, что **concurrency** и **parallelism** - это не совсем одно и то же. На мой взгляд это вопрос философский. Нужно смотреть реализации конкретных концепций в конкретных языках программирования для понимания деталей. Вот например **асинхронность** - это действительно не тоже самое, что параллельное исполнение.

Вообще, есть же такой же глагол калька с английского "конкурировать" и существительное "конкуренция", возможно в данном случае это вот про **конкуренцию** за некоторый ресурс. И обычно такая конкуренция обеспечивается именно тем, что разные ветви кода выполняются в разных потоках.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050222/what-is-the-difference-between-concurrency-and-parallelism

Answer (score 2):

Конкурентными называются операции, которые пересекаются друг с другом во времени. Например, конкурентной записью в словарь называется ситуация, когда один поток начинает записывать что-то в словарь пока второй поток заканчивает делать то же самое.

Comment: Я в целом то согласен, но тогда объясните, как это будет выглядеть в случае "возвести значения в квардрат КОНКУРЕНТНО"?

Comment: @CrazyElf в принципе у меня есть решение, на случай, если под конкурентностью подразумевается параллельные вычисления. Но вот само слово конкурентность - сбивает с толку.